# CalledProcessError when using setup.py in Google DataFlow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have the following error when using setup.py for installing dependencies on my DataFlow workers :

```
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/apache-beam-2.27.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/processes.py in check_output(*args, **kwargs)
     90     try:
---> 91       out = subprocess.check_output(*args, **kwargs)
     92     except OSError:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    410     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 411                **kwargs).stdout
    412 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in run(input, capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    511             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 512                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    513     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)

CalledProcessError: Command '['/root/apache-beam-2.27.0/bin/python', 'setup.py', 'sdist', '--dist-dir', '/tmp/tmpcljk596r']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

My Setup.py file is exactly the one proposed by Apache Beam, I want to install 2 python modules and one by apt-get :

```
CUSTOM_COMMANDS = [
    ['apt-get', 'update'],
    ['apt-get', '--assume-yes', 'install', 'poppler-utils']
]

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = ['pdf2image', 'poppler-utils']
```

It is really painfull error as it seems to me that I am using the setup.py option exactly the way it should be for installing dependencies with apt-get on my workers.

As usual, using the DirectRunner works like a charm :)

My configuration :

- Apache Beam 2.27.0 on Python 3.7.9
- DataFlow notebook on GCP
- (got the same error when running DataFlow outside the notebook)

Thanks for your help

Best regards

Jerome

Comment: Could you solve it?

Comment: Having the same issue on our Composer 2 instance. All we've been able to do is catch this specific Exception and retry the Airflow task which seems to then succeed on any subsequent runs

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced a similar error... took forever to fix. I cannot speak for all platforms or for your specific setup.py, but I can share how I fixed the similar problem on Windows, and hopefully this can help you.

In the apache beam source, it runs the setup command with Python's subprocess module (where you see the CalledProcessError originating from). On Windows, it forces the parameter shell=True when calling check_output, meaning that it runs the command in a platform specific shell (i.e. usually cmd.exe on windows).

As a first step, validate that the command you see throwing the CalledProcessException isn’t actually throwing an error by running it manually in your shell. In my case, the command (Python setup.py study...) was working as expected when run manually.

Then, if you are on Windows, make sure that all of the autorun commands on powershell/cmd are functioning as expected and not throwing errors. If you are not on windows, I would think that you should validate whether or not shell=True is being used by your beam code, and if so make sure the autorun scripts for your shell are working.

In my case, the Python command being run by Beam was working fine when run manually. But when executed in a sub process with shell=True, a broken auto run command in my shell caused beam to receive an error code from the sub process and believe the Python command had failed.

-Tyler